# Loop through an entire column to find a value

Tags: excel, vba

How can I loop through all the rows of a column in VBA ?

Here is my sample :

```
Function FindRow(Item As String, Rng As range) As Variant

Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

For col = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
    For row = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count        
        If Rng.Cells(row, col).Value = Item Then
            FindRow = row + Rng.row - 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next row
Next col

FindRow = CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrNA)

End Function
```

If my range is a single column, Rng.Columns.Count is 1 and Rng.Rows.Count is 1048576. My function stops before entering the second For. If I add a watch on Rng.Cells(row, col).Value, I got an

```
<Application-defined or object-defined error>
```

in the watch window, but no pop-up.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

**Second solution**

Using Rng.Find(Item).Row

```
Function FindRow(Item As String, Rng As range) As Variant

FindRow = Rng.Find(Item).Row

End Function
```

/!\ It returns #VALUE instead of #N/A if the Item is not in the range

Comment: Why are you looping through over a million rows when you can just use `Range.Find()` ?

Comment: But if you do want to loop through, maybe set i = 1 and use "Do until i > Rng.Columns.Count" and at the end i=i+1

Comment: I need to find a value in a matrix that covers mutliple columns and rows. I figured it would be easier if I made my own functions. I'm totally new to VBA and Excel (just started a week ago). I did not know Range.Find(), as I can see it does not return a position but the content of the first occurrence (I may use it wrong)

Comment: I'm still learning almost everytime... Thx SO and J-F!
Maybe try both ByRef and ByVal parameters, or switch row from integer to double or long (probably not a problem...) because your code seem good

Comment: @Sara Range.Find() returns the default property of the range object, which is the value. You can just use Range.Find().Row to return the Row property.

Comment: Thak you I'll try it

Comment: @Sara you can use something like `Set rngVar = rng.Find("something")` and then `rngVar.Address` or `rngVar.Row` etc to get the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the built-in `MATCH` function?

```
=MATCH(C3,A:A,0)
```

[image]

---

... because you want to search many columns at once. To do so, you can use this UDF:

```
Function FindRow(lookFor As String, rng As Range)
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long

    'Read contents of range into a Variant array
    v = rng.Value 

    'Loop through contents to locate the desired element
    For iRow = LBound(v, 1) To UBound(v, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(v, 2) To UBound(v, 2)
            If v(iRow, iCol) = lookFor Then
                FindRow = iRow
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow



    FindRow = CVErr(XlCVError.xlErrNA)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I would do this, but to OP just for future reference as well, when looping through all the rows in a worksheet, you are better off declaring the variable type as Long instead of Integer, because the Integer data type can only store values up to 32768.

Comment: I need to loop through a unknown amount of columns and rows

Comment: @Dave Entirely pedantic I know, but an integer can hold up to 32,767 in VBA </ocd>

Comment: I forgot to mention up to but not including... ;)

Comment: <3 I didn't knew that we can use an array with a range like this, that's awesome! :)

Comment: @R3uK step through this line -> `myArray = [A1:A10]` and then look at `myArray` in the locals window. ;)